How to save and restore printer device mode to file in Delphi?
I would like to save all printer settings of the chosen printer to a file in hex format. And later, load them from the file.
How do I do that?
I tried with the following. This is not in hex format.
procedure SaveDevModeToFile(deviceHandle: THandle; filePath: string);
var
  pDevmode: PDeviceMode;
  fs : TFileStream;
begin
  pDevMode := GlobalLock(deviceHandle);
  if pDevmode <> nil then
    try
      fs:= TFileStream.Create(filePath, fmCreate);
      try
        fs.WriteBuffer(PChar(pDevmode)^, sizeof(TDevicemode));
      finally
        fs.Free;
      end;
    finally
      GlobalUnlock(deviceHandle);
    end;
end;

procedure AskSettingsAndSave;
var MyPrinter, MyDriver, MyPort: array[0..255] of Char;
  DeviceHandle: THandle;
begin
  if PrinterSetupDialog1.Execute(Self.Handle) then
    begin
      Printer.GetPrinter(MyPrinter, MyDriver, MyPort, DeviceHandle);

      if DeviceHandle <> 0 then
      begin
        SaveDevModeToFile(DeviceHandle, 'd:\temp\dm.txt');
      end;
    end;
end;


Hex format is just a base16 representation of binary data! So either stick with writing binary data to file or convert it before with IntToHex and write it as string.

There is no such thing as hex format. Hex is a display feature for readability by humans. If you want to save it properly, save it in binary and not text. Text is for things that are going to be read by human eyes, and the contents of a DEVMODE structure are for the most part not textual. And if you're writing binary data, for your own sanity do NOT use the .txt extension.

Also, if you do save the file as binary, and then use a hex viewer application, you will see that that file is displayed in hex format. You can also open a text file in a hex viewer application, and that text will also be displayed in hex format. As I said, hex format is just a display type, not a data storage type.

d:\temp  Sounds familiar ;-)

Worst case you can go back to declaring an old fashioned file of TDevicemode and then read/write one record.

d:\temp\dm.txt is just a test path, obviously.
DEVMODE structure is only a part of the file. Consider, as example, writing a json file that has one property containing DEVMODE and a lot of other properties. It is better not to use binary format.
But the problem is not "the hex format". Is to obtain the complete DEVMODE structure and then restore back.
